Where do I begin with fixing my house?
I left this house around 2 years ago before moving to college. In that time, it has massively deteriorated, partly due to its poor construction, and partly because it was robbed and trashed around 4 times while I was away.
I cannot even begin to list all the problems with the house as it, but here are a few pressing ones-

Severe cockroach infestation (mainly in the kitchen)
The entire house has been affected by wood mite colonies. They have chewed through all of the kitchen, the walls and and floors are COVERED in their little mud lines. Most of the wooden doors and door frames are no longer usable because they been chewed into oblivion.
List There is just massive amounts of trash everywhere, I don't even know where to begin the trash collection, and where to dispose of it. This includes rotting wood from the doors and the kitchen. Expired and spoiled food items in the kitchen. Other misc. items that I don't have the use for anymore.

I understand this place requires a complete renovation, but the problem is that I am only here for a month, and I will leave again for 2+ years after that. Most of the stuff I am hesitant to get done bcs I am afraid it will get undone while I am away, so it will be a waste of money. However, I still want to make this place livable at the very least, because I am going to need to stay here and don't have another place to go to.
On the brighter side tho, the water and electricity is functional, and I cleaned most of the dirt that had settled on everything. Please let me know what I should do about this.

start with a fumigation tent

Professional exterminator does seem the place to start. The "wood mites" sound like termites, given the mention of mud tunnels, so eliminating them may require removing a lot of the damaged wood entirely... and you want the pros to check whether any of the structural members of the house have been damaged. Frankly, the place sounds like something I would sell off to be demolished and replaced with new construction, but if you are thinking if trying to live in it I presume that isn't an option.  Good luck, but be prepared for the  risk of it being condemned as uninhabitable.

Is this an x-y problem? I’d sell and use part of the money for the month worth of housing you need.

There's no way you'll get the house livable in short enough time that you can live there most of the month in a reasonable state of peace. I agree with @kelsham: sell it for the cost of the land (demolition of the house) and live in a long-stay hotel or a friend's house for the month. (Maybe even a campground if you'd like that idea.)

Voting to close this question.   We can't tell you where to live this month.  You were able to pay for college and now you have an education so hopefully you can figure that out.  As for the house, if you ask a new question about specific elements of it, with photos, and how to go about restoring them, maybe you'll get answers.  Keep it narrow.  But if the plan is to let it rot another 2 years, the answers to questions about repair or demolish are big picture economic ones and depend on the neighborhood so we can't answer those either.

If you want to DIY, you're going to need help.  The amount of labor would take too long for one person to stay on top of it all.
Go to the store and get a box of contractor bags, a paint respirator, gloves, roach paste, and basic cleaning supplies.  Make sure you have a reliable supply of drinking water and bathroom necessities on site.  Arrange for a roll-off trash dumpster.
If this already sounds overwhelming, then this isn't the right strategy for you.

Houses require constant maintenance. You just can't expect to leave a house empty for 2 years and come back to a usable structure. Even if a small leak in the roof will eventually develop into a hole that will destroy your ceilings, floors, flood the foundation and destroy your house. And an empty house is a magnet for vandals and squatters. They have an eye for abandoned houses. Who is doing the yard? Snow? Do you have anyone who can visit the house weekly, just to watch for termites, leaks, or squatters? If not, keeping the house is not realistic.
But let's say you solve the above issue, you then need to evaluate if the termites have destroyed the house. Remove some of the wall coverings (sheetrock, panels, whatever) and look at the studs. Go to the basement and look at the mud sills and the floor joists, go into the attic and look at the ceiling joists and the rafters, etc. If the termites have gotten to these, then your goose is cooked, and you already lost the house.
So assuming you still have a salvageable house:

Rent roll-off dumpsters and empty the contents of the house. If you have the money, call a cleanup service.
Call an exterminator to treat for termites and mice. The cockroaches will not be a problem once you clean the food from the kitchen.
Protect against vandals and squatters with a motion-activated trail cam with cell phone connection, then call the police when the camera sends you a signal that people are in.

